# Emacs scrolls at random

Tags: emacs

Now and again when I am viewing a file emacs randomly scrolls the buffer, using the function bound to my mouse wheel

It's not critical, but it's an annoyance.
I am on linux, using emacs 23.3.1.

Comment: Bad mouse? Touching the touchpad by accident? Some form of interference with the remote mouse?

Comment: Yes, it was a bad mouse. 2 years ago :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try typing <kbd>C-h l</kbd> after it happens.  This will display the last few input events.  If you see `<wheel-up>` or `<wheel-down>` in the list, then emacs is getting actual mouse wheel events and the problem may be with your hardware or OS.